# What controls are used for this form?

Tags: .net, winforms

Please see attached image: http://i54.tinypic.com/1zbuskp.png

I'm wondering about what main controls that makes up this layout of 3 "panels" with header bars.

I assume it's a set of SplitContainers, but then I'm unsure if what's inside are panels, or individual forms.. Is it possible to determine from this image? And what is used for the header bars?

As can be seen, the headerbars changes slightly color when each panel is selected. In image the middle one was clicked.

[image]

Comment: These might as well be user defined controls using multiple other controls within it. I may recognize a `SplitContainer` which contains also two Panel within itself where you can drop your other controls onto, then, perhaps some `DataGridView`s or `ListView`s, some `LinkButton`s, `ScrollBar`s... Just guessing here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spy++ and/or reflector to  find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This does look like SplitContainers.
Inside each section it's either a panel with controls inside it, or a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx) (can't be a form because you can't put a form inside another one).

I don't know what the header bars are, could be a custom control with some background image and a label over it.

Answer (score 0):

This could just as easily be three panels with controls, each docked, and possibly with a splitter in between. The highlighted titlebar could easily be custom drawn.